# Authorize (login) from Swashbuckle Swagger interface in .NET framework

Tags: c#, swashbuckle

Using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`, I got a Swagger interface for my .NET core REST API, with an "Authorize" button that takes me to my Single Sign-On server:

[image: .NET core screenshot]

I need to do the same in an ASP.NET application based on .NET Framework 4.8, using the `Swashbuckle` package, but I don't get the Authorize button:

[image: .NET framework screenshot]

This is my initialization code:

```cs
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using Swashbuckle.Application;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace Test {

    public class SwaggerConfig {
        public static void Register() {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c => {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "Rest Test");
                    c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                        .Description("OAuth2 Implicit Grant")
                        .Flow("implicit")
                        .AuthorizationUrl("https://keycloak.some.test/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth")
                        .TokenUrl("https://keycloak.some.test/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect");
                    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c => {
                    c.EnableOAuth2Support(
                        clientId: "test-client",
                        clientSecret: null,
                        realm: "test",
                        appName: "Swagger UI"
                    );
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the authorize button with Swashbuckle on ASP.NET, using the .NET framework and not .NET core? Am I missing some initialization?

I tried searching for this issue, but all the answers and documentation I've found were related to .NET core, and for me it's essential to use .NET framework 4.8.

Comment: Does your test/test endpoint have a AuthorizeAttribute attached to it? Or the Net Framework equivalent of that that i don't know of? Maybe it help showing how the endpoint/controller signatures (especially its attributes) look.

Comment: Curios how does Swashbuckle.AspNetCore get together with Net. Framework 4.8? OK seen it. The very old versions aren't for NetStandard 2 and "might" work.

Comment: @Ralf in .NET framework version I'm using Swashbuckle, not Swashbuckle.AspNetCore. I've updated the question.

Comment: Also, I haven't defined any AuthorizeAttribute, I'll see if that changes anything.

Comment: Try getting it to work without [Authorize] which should allow any user.  OAUTH2 should work with Net 4.8.  Some people it works, and other have had issues.  Get the status code returned in the response which will help find the answer.

Comment: The API works, that's not the issue. I would just like to have an automatically created authorize button, so that I can login and test authorization.